# Exploration or navigation

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, exploration, hector-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I used hector slam to make a map of the environment. Now, I want to repeat the map using navigation or exploration. I installed hector_navigation and navigation packages but I don't know if I have to make changes and what commands to give. Can anyone tell me a complete tutorial or give me any information about steps to take? Because I have several launch files and nodes, but I do not know what to use and how to use them. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228444/exploration-or-navigation/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For exploration, you don't even need to create a map in advance.

You can launch hector_slam, the [hector_exploration_planner](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation/blob/catkin/hector_exploration_node/launch/exploration_planner.launch), and the [hector_exploration_controller](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation/tree/catkin/hector_exploration_controller/src). The result will be simultaneous exploration and mapping.

For navigation, you can use your map with the standard ROS navigation stack. See http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-08**:
Thank you! After hector_slam, I had launch "roslaunch hector_exploration_node exploration_planner.launch" and I had this error: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' becaus

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-08**:
...they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.. canTransform returned after 0.102339 timeout was 0.1. And when I type "rosrun hector_exploration_controller simple_exploration_controller" I had: [ WARN] [1457429139.712816935]: Service call for exploration service failed.

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-08**:
What am I doing wrong? What display and what topic should I change in rviz?

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-08**:
Can you check this my link? http://answers.ros.org/question/228516/error-in-exploration-and-slam/
Thank you!